# Set drawable dynamically for AnalogClock widget

Tags: android, widget, runtime, drawable

How to do that?

I have AnalogClock on my xml. And I want drawable for the android:dial to change programatically.

I tried

```
remoteviews.setImageViewResource(R.id.AnalogClock, R.drawable.w0);
```

or

```
remoteviews.setInt(R.id.AnalogClock, "setDialResource", R.drawable.w0);
```

Both can not accomplish it.
Anyone manage to do this?

Comment: First of all, you shouldn't use AnalogClock as an id name : analogClock would sound better for conventions. you are using remoteViews, is it because you are making a widget ?

Comment: Yes, I'm developing widget. I'm using Android default component AnalogClock. Not the id name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally make it works.
I put transparent image on AnalogClock android:dial
Then use FrameLayout to overlay ImageView and AnalogClock.

Then use

> remoteviews.setInt(R.id.ImageView, "setBackgroundResource",
>   R.drawable.w0);

to change the ImageView image.
It is feasible solution at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Normally `remoteviews.setImageViewResource(R.id.AnalogClock, R.drawable.w0)` should do the trick. Are you sure that the View refferenced by `R.id.AnalogClock` is of type `ImageView`

Comment: Nope. I'm using Android component AnalogClock not ImageView. I use android:dial to set the clock background.